# Pandas merge объеденение с условием

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Друзья, здравствуйте!

Не могу объединить два pandas df в один правильно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как вы догадались, надо в первый вписать затраты средние из второго, если проект и направление совпадают.

Comment: Замените картинку текстом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) по умолчанию использует столбцы с одинаковыми именами в качестве столбцов объединения. Если удалить из первого DF столбец `'затраты среднее'` и столбец `'затраты факт'` из второго, то общими останутся `['проект','направление вызова']`. Столбец `'затраты факт'` - берется из DF1, `'затраты среднее''` - из DF2:

```
res = df1.drop('затраты среднее', 1).merge(df2.drop('затраты факт',1))
```